# Receive sensor data, publish on webpage - http.POST(jsonData)

Tags: http, post, arduino

I'm new to programming a php page, so I may ask too much, hope you bear out with me.

**My case**

I have an Arduino Bee Hive monitoring system that sends live data, temperature and weight.

On my LAN I have a web server on my Synology NAS running php 7.4

I think this code is based websocket, not sure.

- Arduino device has IP 192.168.0.52
- Server IP 192.168.0.5, http port 9978, https not enabled

On web server no values are seen, if received I don't know.

Code for Arduino sender side is running and also state that "Data sent successfully":

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

const char* host = "192.168.0.5"; //web server synology NAS
const int port = 9978;  // http port Synology

const char* ssid = "nettUser";
const char* password = "nettPass";
//web login
char username[] = "serverUser";
char userpassword[] = "serverPass";


void loop() {
  // Read sensor values and store in temperature and humidity
  // Read the temperature and weight values
  float temperature = 25.0;    // for php test purpose, fixed values
  float weight = 50.0;

  // Create a JSON object to store the data
  String jsonData = "{\"temperature\":" + String(temperature) + ",\"weight\":" + String(weight) + "}";

  // Create an instance of the HTTPClient class
  HTTPClient http;

  // Make a POST request to the server
  http.begin("http://" + String(host) + ":" + String(port));
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.setAuthorization(username, userpassword);
  int httpCode = http.POST(jsonData);

  // Check the response code
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    Serial.println("Data sent successfully");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error sending data");
  }

  // Close the connection
  http.end();
 
  Serial.print("[WiFi] IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println(temperature_f);
  Serial.println(humidity_f);

  delay(5000);
  }
}
```

[Arduino output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvN3O.png)

Server side:
Code I found on internet, with some modifications

saved as index.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function updateData() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://192.168.0.52:80");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = data.temperature;
              document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = data.weight;
            } else {
              console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
          }
        };
        xhr.send();
      }
      setInterval(updateData, 1000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HiveMon - v 1</h3>
    <h3>Temperature: <span id="temperature"></span>&#8451;</h3>
    <h3>Weight: <span id="weight"></span>%</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlI3F.png)

Code above is running now.

I have not tried much, but I tested in web server code to enter web server ip 192.168.0.5 instead of 192.168.0.52 with no help

Comment: Hey, have you checked out other communities? I would also recommend posting your question here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm a little confused by the above code. The Arduino appears to send a POST request to your webserver ( on the Synology ) and the Javascript AJAX code is sending a GET request to the Arduino every 1 second? Surely the AJAX request should trigger the Arduino code to simply `print` the data rather than send http request ( because Javascript will not process the POST request )

Comment: Presumably `temperature_f` and `humidity_f` are variables on the Arduino based upon the sensor reading - these are not declared before `Serial.println()` is called

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. I have found a different code so I will make a new post.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to get a "live" update of your sensor's data on your web page, right?

If so, I may suggest implementing the following pattern:

[image]

From the above, you are only missing the request handler!

This mechanism is straightforward; when Arduino sends a request, it tells the request handler to save the data temporarily into the data handler and any time the web app pulls data, the request handler responds with the data previously submitted by Arduino.

So following is the code that implements this

***request_handler.php*** (Created at your root folder)

```
<?php
$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input"); //as you send data as raw json

if ($post_data) { //when request comes from arduino, you will have post data
    $json_data = json_encode($post_data);
    if (file_put_contents("data.txt", $json_data)) {
        echo "Ok";
    } else {
        http_response_code(400); //when data did not save
        echo "Bad Request";
    }
} else { //when the web app make a call to the request handler
    $previous_data = file_get_contents("data.txt");
    echo $previous_data;
}
```

And slightly change your arduino code to :

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

const char* host = "192.168.0.5"; //web server synology NAS
const int port = 9978;  // http port Synology

const char* ssid = "nettUser";
const char* password = "nettPass";
//web login
char username[] = "serverUser";
char userpassword[] = "serverPass";


void loop() {
  // Read sensor values and store in temperature and humidity
  // Read the temperature and weight values
  float temperature = 25.0;    // for php test purpose, fixed values
  float weight = 50.0;

  // Create a JSON object to store the data
  String jsonData = "{\"temperature\":" + String(temperature) + ",\"weight\":" + String(weight) + "}";

  // Create an instance of the HTTPClient class
  HTTPClient http;

  // Make a POST request to the server
  http.begin("http://" + String(host) + ":" + String(port) + "/request_handler.php");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.setAuthorization(username, userpassword);
  int httpCode = http.POST(jsonData);

  // Check the response code
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    Serial.println("Data sent successfully");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error sending data");
  }

  // Close the connection
  http.end();
 
  Serial.print("[WiFi] IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println(temperature_f);
  Serial.println(humidity_f);

  delay(5000);
  }
}
```

Finally your ***index.php***

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function updateData() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://192.168.0.52:80/request_handler.php");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = data.temperature;
              document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = data.weight;
            } else {
              console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
          }
        };
        xhr.send();
      }
      setInterval(updateData, 1000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HiveMon - v 1</h3>
    <h3>Temperature: <span id="temperature"></span>&#8451;</h3>
    <h3>Weight: <span id="weight"></span>%</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, regarding database, that must be next step. Over my skills. Per today my goal is to save the data in a file ';' separated as a backup. Today I populate my readings on mydevices.com (cayenne)

Comment: Did you try the above solution? It is using a simple file to make sync everything!

Comment: Solution: Hi, I changed the request handler and now it works: main code is: <?php
$temperature = $_GET["temperature"];
$weight = $_GET["weight"];

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
$date = date("Y:m:d;H:i");
$data = "$date;$temperature;$weight\n";

$file = "data.txt";
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);